# What happens when a Roth 401(k) contribution interferes with payroll taxes?

Tags: united-states, contribution, roth-401k, payroll-taxes

I tried looking up this up on Google but there were too many irrelevant search results. I also perused through the Roth 401(k) Plan documents but was not able to find a section on this.

My salary is in the 30-40k range. My net income per pay period is less than 50 dollars because I contribute around 3/4's of my income to the Roth 401(k). I was wondering: I can theoretically contribute up to 90% per pay period since this is the limit according to the Plan, what happens if I elect to contribute a percentage that cuts into the income that usually goes to payroll taxes?

Would a company's accounting department even allow this to occur? Would it just be as simple as having a higher tax bill at the end of the year? Or, given that the accounting department does not care or does not catch it, would the IRS come after me for under-withholding?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Anecdotal, but my wife's payroll department simply ignored a salary deferral request which would have caused more to be withheld than she had available. They didn't contact her to reject the request, they just ignored it. So, I think the lesson there is that there is no substitute for contacting your payroll/hr/benefits department and asking.

Comment: Careful if you contributing that high of a % to a Roth 401k/403b or Roth 457. My wife and I max out retirement plans early in the year. It was never an issue with a traditional 401k or 403b. With the Roth versions we had to dial back from 83 % to 65 %
HR never notified us as to why.
Has happened at three different employers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll simply have to ask your HR department how they would handle this. My guess is that withholding would happen first, and the remainder would be eligible to try to meet your percentage, if possible. If it's met, then you get cut a check for the rest, and if not, you simply don't get a paycheck. The reason I believe it would be done this way is because of the exact situation you described- where someone might owe more tax money than they have.

If (and only if) you have another source of income (or a lot of savings) you may have incentive to do as you suggest. One thing you could do is increase your allowances on your W4 to reduce your withholding, leaving more for the 401k. You would make up the difference by decreasing your allowances or adding additional tax on your other jobs' W4s, or making extra quarterly payments on self employment income.

Or, you could max out the traditional 401k instead and avoid the problem completely. I wouldn't recommend this though in your position, particularly if you believe you'll be in a higher tax bracket later in life.

Comment: I think you are right, going to HR is the solution. It is interesting though that you mention the withholding would happen first. I guess it depends on the relationship between the accounting department and the plan provider. Would it not raise some flags if the plan provider was not able to pull the full percentage of gross income I had elected? I am almost curious enough to try this.

Comment: @coffeeguy - I think it's easier to conceptualize if you think of it as a push from your company's bank account to the 401k plan instead of a pull (even if you configure it on the provider side).

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it makes a lot of sense. It seems the question in my comment would be a non-issue then, if anything the provider would just probably just email me to let me know of the situation.

Comment: Technically you aren't supposed to increase your allowances above what your situation dictates. However, if you do have multiple jobs, as far as I know you can distribute the allowances however you see fit, as well as the extra $ withholding that you probably also have.

Comment: @stannius - right, which is why i added the "if (and only if)". The most important thing is to get it right. This is exact scenario happens a lot with spouses when both have 401k and one makes a lot more than the other. The lower income spouse artificially inflates the dependents and the other adds additional withholding so they both can max out the 401k (if roth).

Comment: @TTT indeed; what I am pointing out/attempting to clarify is that technically, you aren't allowed to write an excessive number of allowances on one form, and then make up for it with extra $ withholding on the other form. The total number of allowances you claim is supposed to be supported by the facts of your tax situation.

Comment: @stannius - I'm a perfectionist so I appreciate the nitpick! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @stannius - I actually was thinking the same thing (can you legally inflate allowances?) and after a little bit of research I convinced myself that in this situation it would be ok. I don't know how to prove that though. It basically comes down to if you know you will be getting a refund (for any reason), you can make adjustments to decrease that refund.

Comment: @TTT I've looked into it too. I *used* to think you could just write whatever you wanted on the W-4 form(s), and as long as you had the right amount withheld by the end of the year, it was OK. Later, I learned that I was wrong. Specifically, pub 505 states "You can claim only the number of allowances to which you are entitled." and "You may have to pay a penalty of $500 if [...] You have no reasonable basis for those statements or allowances at the time you prepare your Form W-4."

Comment: @stannius - I think this quote from pub 505 seems to allow it: "If you have income from more than one job at the same time, complete only one set of Form W-4 worksheets. Then split your allowances between the Forms W-4 for each job. You can’t claim the same allowances with more than one employer at the same time. You can claim all your allowances with one employer and none with the other(s), or divide them any other way."

Comment: @TTT I agree that you can split the allowed allowances however you want, including claiming all of them on one W-4 and then 0 on another one. But you can't claim more allowances than you're allowed on one W-4, and then make up for it on another W-4 with extra $. Anyways we're kind of in the weeds here, sounds like we basically agree.

Comment: @stannius - right- that is different. I can't find anything explicitly saying you can or cannot do it, but I also can't think of a reason why the irs would care if they audited you and saw that you did. They still get their money, and on time, so my gut feeling is it would be allowed. But yeah, we're definitely on the same page regarding the overall intent.